# specific non linear pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I would really appreciate to hear your insights or comments about the following problem:
Consider the following non linear pde:
let $\Omega$ be the unit square with vertices at (0,0),(1,0),(0,1) and (1,1)
Consider $\triangle u - u^3 = 0$ and $ u = f(x,y)$ on $\partial \Omega$
where $f= \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ when $|x-\frac{1}{2}| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and zero otherwise... what could be said about the energy as $\epsilon$ approaches zero?

If in particular there is a link with these kind of pdes please let me know...thanks